# how to convert ISO date time to YYYYMMDDHHmmss string format?

Tags: javascript

I have a date time in string in this ISO format:

```
2023-08-07T09:38:43+07:00
```

but now I need to convert it to YYYYMMDDHHmmss format, so I expect I will get this string

```
20230807093843
```

how to do that using Javascript without using Moment or another libarary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the string and then [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) the undesired characters:

```js
const formatted = "2023-08-07T09:38:43+07:00".slice(0, 19).replaceAll(/[-:T]/g, "");

console.log(formatted === "20230807093843"); // true
```

Comment: alternatively ``[-:T]|\+.*`` without using the slice fn. :)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76982532/how-to-convert-iso-date-time-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-string-format/76982609#comment135710244_76982609) @OMiShah That approach wouldn't work for any time zone west of UTC (e.g. `2023-08-07T09:38:43-04:00`) since it hardcodes the `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Here this is one way of doing it I guess.

```js
   
const originalDate = "2023-08-07T09:38:43+07:00";

// Parse the original date string
const parsedDate = new Date(originalDate);

// Extract individual components
const year = parsedDate.getFullYear();
const month = (parsedDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = parsedDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const hours = parsedDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const minutes = parsedDate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const seconds = parsedDate.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');

// Create the final formatted date string
const formattedDate = `${year}${month}${day}${hours}${minutes}${seconds}`;

console.log(formattedDate); // Output: 20230807093843
```